# How can I get the level by given experience?

Tags: javascript, math

I have a formula that calculates the experience based on a certain level and another that calculates the level based on the given experience.
But the second function does not return the expected value.

```js
const levels = 40;
const xp_for_first_level = 1000;
const xp_for_last_level = 1000000;

const getExperience = level => {
  const B = Math.log(xp_for_last_level / xp_for_first_level) / (levels - 1);
  const A = xp_for_first_level / (Math.exp(B) - 1.0);

  const old_xp = Math.round(A * Math.exp(B * (level - 1)));
  const new_xp = Math.round(A * Math.exp(B * level));

  return new_xp - old_xp;
};

const getLevel = experience => {
  const B = Math.log(xp_for_last_level / xp_for_first_level) / (levels - 1);
  const A = xp_for_first_level / (Math.exp(B) - 1.0);

  return Math.ceil(Math.log(experience / A) / B);
};

console.log(getLevel(xp_for_first_level)); // -9
console.log(getLevel(xp_for_last_level)); // 30
```

Expected result 1 and 40, but returns -9 and 30.

Can anyone help?

Anyone enlighten me, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the formula should change, i tried with this and it given correct return.

```
const getLevel = experience => {
  const B = Math.log(xp_for_last_level / xp_for_first_level) / (levels + 1);
  const A = xp_for_first_level - 1;
  return Math.ceil(Math.log(experience / A) / B);
};
```

Comment: `const getLevel = experience => {
  const B = Math.log(xp_for_last_level / xp_for_first_level) / (levels - 1);
  const A = xp_for_first_level - 1.0;

  return Math.ceil(Math.log(experience / A) / B);
};`
This worked perfectly. Thank you for clarifying me!